# How to replace tags in innerHtml Angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8, innerhtml

Hello here is my code  -

```
<span  [innerHtml]="question.description | SafePipe: 'html'" style="font-weight:500;" class="ml-1"></span>
```

On my website when inspected i see my span tag contains `<p>` tags in which i get the whole text

```
<span>
    <p>  </p> </span>
```

i want to replace inner `<p>` tags with `<span>` tag. How can i achieve this in angular 8

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your prop `question.description` already has the `p` tag on the string.

Angular also has `innerText` so you can try: `<span  [innerText]="question.description" ...`

Comment: hi, we are uploading data from a text editor which is build as another application. so with [innerText] I get my padding issue solved but I get the whole html tags.. for example - <p style= "color:blue"> Content .. .. .. ... . . . ... </p>

Comment: so my assumption is true. you have html on your string. If you cant change the src data, I don't know...

Comment: yeah, we are unable to change it. still looking for answers.